# Update Nested Objects in React Native using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change the properties of objects inside of an object and
trying to add new properties to these objects but keeping the old values.

I can't find out how to get the right nested object by index, not id because
the id can be different from the .map index.

This is what I got so far, the Object names are for testing purposes
only and maybe the "updateNestedObject" can be run in the parent?

Thank you in advance and sorry if this is a noob question.

Neval

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';


function ObjectScreen() {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
     id: 1,
     name: 'Test Object',
     nested: [
         {
           id: 1,
           title: 'Object 1',
         },
         {
           id: 2,
           title: 'Object 1',
         }
     ]

  });


  function editNested({nestedObject, index, setState}) {


    const updateNestedObject = () => {

       setState(prevState => ({
         nested: [
             ...prevState.nested,
             [prevState.nested[index].comment]: 'Test Comment',
         },
       }));
   
    }

    return (
        <View>
          <Text>{object.title}</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            name="comment"
            onChangeText={updateNestedObject}

          />
        </View>
    );
  }

  return  (
    <>
      <Text>{state.name}</Text>

      { state.nested.map((nestedObject, key)=>{
          return (
            <editNested key={key} index={key} object={object} nestedObject={nestedObject}/>
          )
        })}

    </>
  )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default ObjectScreen;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few issues:

1. JSX component name `editNested` should start with a capital letter.
2. And `editNested` component should be on its own function, should not define inside another component which caused your `TextInput` to lose focus after each render cycle.
3. The `setState` call should be changed like below:

```
const updateNestedObject = (text) => {
  setState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    nested: prevState.nested.map((item) =>
      item.id === nestedObject.id ? { ...item, value: text } : item
    )
  }));
};
```

Try the code below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from "react-native";

function EditNested({ nestedObject, setState }) {
  const updateNestedObject = (text) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      nested: prevState.nested.map((item) =>
        item.id === nestedObject.id ? { ...item, value: text } : item
      )
    }));
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{nestedObject.title}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={updateNestedObject}
        value={nestedObject.value}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ObjectScreen() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    id: 1,
    name: "Test Object",
    nested: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "Object 1",
        value: ""
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "Object 1",
        value: ""
      }
    ]
  });

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <>
      <Text>{state.name}</Text>

      {state.nested.map((nestedObject, key) => {
        return (
          <EditNested
            key={key}
            nestedObject={nestedObject}
            setState={setState}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10
  }
});

export default ObjectScreen;
```

Working Demo

[image: Edit goofy-river-uy5z9e]

Answer (score 0):

As per que you can update nested array with below method

```
const updateNestedObject = (values, item, index) => {
    console.log('values', values);
    const tempMainObj = state;
    const tempArr = state.nested;
    tempArr[index].value = values;
    const updatedObj = { ...tempMainObj, nested: tempArr };
    setState(updatedObj);
  };
```

Full Example

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';

function ObjectScreen() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test Object',
    nested: [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Object 1',
        value: '',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Object 1',
        value: '',
      },
    ],
  });

  const updateNestedObject = (values, item, index) => {
    console.log('values', values);
    const tempMainObj = state;
    const tempArr = state.nested;
    tempArr[index].value = values;
    const updatedObj = { ...tempMainObj, nested: tempArr };
    setState(updatedObj);
  };

 
  return (
    <>
      <Text style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>{state.name}</Text>

      {state.nested.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            <TextInput
              value={item?.value}
              style={styles.input}
              name="comment"
              onChangeText={(values) => updateNestedObject(values, item, index)}
            />
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default ObjectScreen;
```

Snack expo: [Live Example](https://snack.expo.dev/pGj4aBkPj)